# Is there an easier way to code this XP to LVL script?

Tags: php, mysql

The system works but I am sure there is another way of coding this in order to make it         easier to access the users level depending on their XP points.

```
$getxp = mysql_query("SELECT `xp` FROM `members` WHERE `id` = '$logged[id]'"); 
$xp = mysql_fetch_array($getxp);
$x = $xp['xp']; 
echo "$x";


$level = MYSQL_QUERY("SELECT * FROM `levels` WHERE `xp` >= '$x' LIMIT 1"); 
while ($n = mysql_fetch_array($level)) {
$mylvl = $n[level];
echo "You are a level $mylvl";
}
```

I have a database table for 'MEMBERS' (ID, USERNAME, PASS, XP) and a table for 'LEVELS' (ID, XP, LEVELS). Let me know of an easier method to get the LVL for the user. Many Thanks!

Comment: Any code examples? I have not experienced SQL JOIN's yet!

Comment: In your example, you will always return the NEXT level of a user, not the current one. example: if you have 18 xp and are level 2(15xp), and want to go to level 3(20xp). Your Query will check where `XP >= 18`. which will return 20, because 15 is not larger. Therefore it will return that you are a level 3, and not a level 2. Hacker!

Comment: Could I use $mylevel - 1; to solve this issue? Just trying to figure out the easiest methods, but with the best security. Thanks for the answers so far!

Comment: If you sort your list, then yeah that would also result in the right level. Ideally i don't think you want to do this, because if you look back at your code in 3 months, you'll be like "Why is there a -1? that makes no sense". Ideally you want to just grab the straight answer right from the database. If it is too hard, or if you're focussing on other things at the moment, then sure, you can use -1.

Comment: I'm going to bet those variables have zero [escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) and that's terrifying. Please, stop using `mysql_query`. It doesn't work better if you yell `MYSQL_QUERY`.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should do it.

```
SELECT `levels` 
FROM `members` m 
LEFT JOIN `levels` l ON m.`xp` >= l.`xp`
WHERE m.`id` = '. $logged[id] .'
ORDER BY `levels` ASC
LIMIT 1;
```

Get all members where your member.id = $logged[id]. Next, link your member.id to all xp-requirements that are smaller than your current exp. This will give you a list of all the levels that you surpassed. Now the only thing you have to do is order them in a way that the highest level is first, and then simply limit it to 1 entry. This should result in the highest level that your exp allows you to have -- therefore your current level.

Note that of course, the more levels you have, the larger the LEFT JOIN becomes, which will end up consuming more memory on your SQL server.

also note you're using MYSQL. This is outdate and will be taken out of the next PHP version. Look into MYSQLi at least, or go straight for PDO. This way you wont have to change all your code once the new PHP releases.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM levels WHERE xp >= (SELECT xp FROM members WHERE id='".$loggedin['id']."')";
```

subselect not a join as you have no keys relating levels to members

Comment: subselects are asking for a slow server

Comment: Not sure why this is -1'd. Technically this is the same query as the one in the first post. Also that sounds like just hating on subqueries. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5831603/sql-server-performance-subselect-or-inner-join

Comment: it is just hating a subselect without reasoning. Because its a single return subselect there is no slow query issues he's talking rubbish.